# looping a function through a folder

Tags: r

I am trying to build a custom function which includes vector manipulation. The function works well after manually entering the path and data name. Each document is a .txt file containing just numbers in one column. 
But there is a large number of files in the folder, and my question is how can I loop my function through every single .txt file?

I have tried to use this code, but I don't get anything done.

```
filenames <- list.files(path=("/folder/"), pattern=".txt")
ldf <- lapply(filenames, read.table)
lapply(ldf, sumfun)
```

Here is a simplyfied version of the code

```
    dataframe <- read.table('folder/dataframe.txt')
    sumfun <- function(a){
      x <- dataframe[1:length(dataframe)-1] 
      y <- dataframe[-1]
      dx <- y-x
      SUM1 <-  sum(dx[which(dx>1)]))^2
      SUM2 <- sum(dx[which(dx<1)]))^2
      SUMtot <- SUM1 + SUM2
       return(SUMtot)
    }

sumfun(dataframe)
```

As I understand it, the problem might be in the x and y vector manipulation?

Comment: did you try using 'apply' function? I would also suggest u to plug in print statements and check what is happening underneath.

Comment: You need replace `dataframe` within your function with `a`, e.g. `x <- a[1:length(a)-1]`. Right now you don't use your input variable within the function.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your function. You define the argument as `a` but use `dataframe` instead. Also there are extra `)`s in the `sum()` operations. It should be:

```
sumfun <- function(a){
  x <- a[1:length(a)-1] 
  y <- a[-1]
  dx <- y-x
  SUM1 <- sum(dx[which(dx>1)])^2
  SUM2 <- sum(dx[which(dx<1)])^2
  SUMtot <- SUM1 + SUM2
  return(SUMtot)
}
```

Moreover, the file names you receive might cause an issue if your working directory isn't in the same location. The following addition will fix that:

```
filenames <- list.files(path=("/folder"), pattern=".txt", full.names = T)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.
 But after running it with the first code:
`filenames <- list.files(path=("/folder/"), pattern=".txt")
ldf <- lapply(filenames, read.table)
lapply(ldf, sumfun)`

I get an error:
`Error in matrix(unlist(value, recursive = FALSE, use.names = FALSE), nrow = nr,  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL`

Comment: As I said, you should also change your reading command to `filenames <- list.files(path=("/folder"), pattern=".txt", full.names = T)`.